# It is possible to download a database in the assets after starting the app

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite

I have an app created with flutter. At the startup, it takes data from a database saved in the assets. On a click of a button, I would like to invoke a download of another database from an address and make this new database to be permanently saved in the assets folder of my app in order to be usable later

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download something to the assets folder and then use that as your new asset. Assets are bundled and deployed with your app.

You would have to download and store the information/database to a given location using e.g. `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` and then load that database if it exists, otherwise load your assets database.